# Finding the Moment Generating Function given f(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, moment-generating-functions

I think I'm having trouble with this because of the absolute value. Otherwise, I know how to solve for the moment generating function. The problem is that show that if a random variable  has the probability density

$$
f(x) = \frac12 e^{-|x|}  \qquad -\infty\lt X \lt \infty    
$$

its moment-generating function is given by

$$
M_x(t) = \frac1{1-t^2}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moment generating function is defined $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$. In your case this is

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|} dx$ =

$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx-|x|} dx$ =

$\frac{1}{2}(\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{tx-|x|} dx  + \int_{0}^\infty e^{tx-|x|} dx)$ =

$\frac{1}{2}(\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{tx+x} dx  + \int_{0}^\infty e^{tx-x} dx)$

You shouldn't have trouble evaluating those integrals now.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It makes so much more sense now!